# TYPO3 (7.6.15) Extbase displayCond in flexform.xml not working in one of two extensions

Tags: typo3, extbase

I've been googling quite a bit about this problem but didn't find a mistake.

I've got a quite simple extension I wrote with Extension Builder that works just as intended. But one small mistake remains.

The extension is used for courses and course-applications. These courses are of different types. If I want to add the plugin-element to a page I have two different types of displaying options for the frontend: one is used for the home page, showing the different types of courses, the other is used for the respective course page to list all the courses of that type and a registration form. This all works perfectly. So when I add a plugin-element to the page I can either choose "Home" or "Course page". When Home is selected no further options should show. When "course page" is selected there should be showing another dropdown element with the different course types.

Only recently I realized that in my flexform I had eliminated the displayCond (don't remember why) and of course it shows the option for the course types with "home" and "course page". BUT if I add the displayCond it doesn't show with either option. Here's the flexform-code with the displayCond:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <T3DataStructure>
    <sheets>
      <general>
        <ROOT>
          <TCEforms>
            <sheetTitle>Kurse</sheetTitle>
          </TCEforms>
          <type>array</type>
          <el>
            <switchableControllerActions>
              <TCEforms>
                <label>Ansicht</label>
                <onChange>reload</onChange>
                <config>
                  <type>select</type>
                  <items type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                      <numIndex index="0">Home</numIndex>
                      <numIndex index="1">Kurse->listHome</numIndex>
                    </numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                      <numIndex index="0">Kursseite</numIndex>
                      <numIndex index="1">Kurse->list;Kunde->sendMail</numIndex>
                    </numIndex>
                  </items>
                </config>
              </TCEforms>
            </switchableControllerActions>
                    <settings.kursTypen>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <label>Kurstyp</label>
                            <config>
                                <type>select</type>
                                <foreign_table>tx_gicourses_domain_model_kurstyp</foreign_table>
                                <foreign_table_where>AND (sys_language_uid=CAST('###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid###' AS UNSIGNED) OR sys_language_uid = '-1') AND tx_gicourses_domain_model_kurstyp.deleted = 0 AND tx_gicourses_domain_model_kurstyp.hidden = 0 order by name</foreign_table_where>
                                <size>1</size>
                                <minitems>1</minitems>
                                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                            </config>
                <displayCond>
                  <OR>
                    <numIndex index="1">FIELD:switchableControllerActions:=:Kurse->list</numIndex>
                  </OR>
                </displayCond>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </settings.kursTypen>
          </el>
        </ROOT>
      </general>
    </sheets>
  </T3DataStructure>
```

FUNNY thing is, that in another extension, where I have an according display-condition, this works just as intended:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <T3DataStructure>
    <sheets>
      <general>
        <ROOT>
          <TCEforms>
            <sheetTitle>Books</sheetTitle>
          </TCEforms>
          <type>array</type>
          <el>
            <switchableControllerActions>
              <TCEforms>
                <label>Ansicht</label>
                <onChange>reload</onChange>
                <config>
                  <type>select</type>
                  <items type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                      <numIndex index="0">Alle</numIndex>
                      <numIndex index="1">Buch->list</numIndex>
                    </numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                      <numIndex index="0">Nach Kategorie</numIndex>
                      <numIndex index="1">Buch->listByCat</numIndex>
                    </numIndex>
                  </items>
                </config>
              </TCEforms>
            </switchableControllerActions>
            <settings.buchKategorie>
              <TCEforms>
                <label>Buchkategorie</label>
                <config>
                  <type>select</type>
                  <foreign_table>tx_gibooks_domain_model_buchkategorie</foreign_table>
                  <foreign_table_where>AND (sys_language_uid=CAST('###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid###' AS UNSIGNED) OR sys_language_uid = '-1') AND tx_gibooks_domain_model_buchkategorie.deleted = 0 AND tx_gibooks_domain_model_buchkategorie.hidden = 0 order by name</foreign_table_where>
                  <size>1</size>
                  <minitems>1</minitems>
                  <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                </config>
                <displayCond>
                  <OR>
                    <numIndex index="1">FIELD:switchableControllerActions:=:Buch->listByCat</numIndex>
                  </OR>
                </displayCond>
              </TCEforms>
            </settings.buchKategorie>
          </el>
        </ROOT>
      </general>
    </sheets>
  </T3DataStructure>
```

The only difference that I had in mind was that the action in the first extension (Kurse->list) was a non-cacheable action in comparison to the one in the second extension (Buch->listByCat) which was a cacheable action. But even with changing this nothing changed when selecting the plugin-element.

Where could this problem originate from? Do I have to check something else? Is there another way of achieving the wanted result?

I've read about several similar problems but none of them stated a problem with the code I have (no typo-mistakes, condition is correct..) although I have read about several bugs that had been related to the displayCond which seemed to be resolved though.

As I'm quite new with TYPO3 I would appreciate if you could point me to files which need to be controlled and/or explain your code. Thank you

For the time being I can leave the option showing on both "Home" and "course page" but it might be quite confusing for someone (an editor) who doesn't really like working with computers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake thanks to Claus Due:

my displayCond before correction:

```
FIELD:switchableControllerActions:=:Kurse->list
```

and after:

```
FIELD:switchableControllerActions:=:Kurse->list;Kunde->sendMail
```

That's what happens when you copy something that's supposed to work but you don't even understand what it does. Thanks to the hint of Claus Due I realized that this was a comparison of strings and that the compared string didn't match with the wanted one.

So if someone wants do use this for something else: you have to use the whole string of actions after "FIELD:switchableControllerActions:=:"...

Fairly easy isn't it... Happy Coding

Comment: Good find, happy to have helped indirectly. For later reference, the docs about displayCond can be found here (for TYPO3 7.6 but also applies to v8). https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Columns/Index.html - from this it seems there *is no way to check if part of the value matches a certain string*, only the opposite is possible (checking if value is one of N values listed as CSV in the displayCond). To actually check if the string value contains another string, you'd need a USER type condition and a custom function that does the checking.

Comment: @ClausDue I've seen the documentation but I didn't find my mistake until you guided me to the solution with the comment about string comparison. I will keep this in mind though... and I've learned something ;) Thanks again for your support.

Answer (score 1):

This is half a shot from the hip, but have you tried this without the `<OR>` segment? Normally you don't need `<AND>` or `<OR>` when you have only a single condition to be checked - and I suspect that this is confusing the condition so it gives false positives. Take this with a grain of salt though - I'm not even sure if that `displayCond` is the right way to check if a string contains another string.

That said, there have been fixes for both FlexForm value resolving/checking and displayCond - so in any case it certainly is worth while to upgrade your TYPO3 version (there have been 7+ bug fix releases since your version).

Comment: I'll try leaving it out and will report back. But still why would this work in one extension and in the other it wouldn't? The course extension is a bit more complex than the book extension yet the same construction of flexform should end up with the same functionality, shouldn't it?

Comment: Leaving out the "or" condition results in both options showing the additional options from displayCond just as if I would leave it out completely

Comment: For the time being I won't upgrade the TYPO3 although I do see your point. Do you have any other idea where this problem might originate from? I've seen that in Versions 8+ they want to implement (or already have implemented ?) error informations for the displayCond (with explanation e.g. syntax error...). This would be really helpful now...

Comment: hahahahahaha... wow, I found the mistake and it was quite simple. Thanks about the hint with checking a string.... see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar. My `displayCond` had no effect. I folwwed the instructions on the [TYPO3 Explained](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/FlexForms/Index.html) tutorial. In the example given the `displayCond` is placed inside the `config` tag.

Not working:

```
<TCEforms>
    <label>Label</label>
    <config>
        <displayCond>FIELD:switchableControllerActions:=:Extension->themes</displayCond>
        <type>input</type>
    </config>
</TCEforms>
```

Working:

```
<TCEforms>
    <label>Label</label>
    <displayCond>FIELD:switchableControllerActions:=:Extension->themes</displayCond>
    <config>
        <type>input</type>
    </config>
</TCEforms>
```

Answer (score -1):

How does the "Kurse->list" look in the Flexform XML? It should read there "Kurse-&gt;list" else you probably have a tag mismatch

Comment: can't you see the code I posted? First snipped is the one not working, the second works perfectly -> seperate extensions...and they both have "->"

Comment: This is not the issue; having such a value would not break the XML parsing and is afair exactly how it gets stored in the DB.